# Image covers ListView on wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm-light

My problem is this:

I got this ListView -

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GameRow1}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GamePiecesTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="12" Grid.Row="1" />
```

and I got this Image -

```
<Image Grid.Column="12" Grid.Row="1"  Source="/Images/Gray_triangle2.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

The problem is that the Image covers my ListView and I can't the ListView  items. is there a way to set picture to be on a grid cell as background?

this is the ItemTemplate btw:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GamePiecesTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding IsWhite , Converter={StaticResource GamePiceToImgSrc}}" Height="50" Width="50" ></Image>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Declare `<Image>` before the `<ListView>`, or set `Panel.ZIndex` to some value greater than zero on the ListView.

Comment: isn't there a Background property on the grid or listview? What you are doing now is fitting two objects into a cell making the latest declared one overlap everything with `stretch = fill`.

Comment: Meehow - there is Background property on the listview , but the problen the the Image strech to fill the listview  and I want it to strech to the cell Height and Weight. As for the Background property on the grid  - I want the Image the strech on a grid cell, not to the entire grid.

Comment: Clemens - it seems like a go-around the problem but I'll use it for now, thanks.

Comment: Clemens  - the Panel.ZIndex  works well. Thank you very much.